# JSF2.0, how commandButton knows which bean to send this

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am starting in JSF2, comming from spring mvc, so I have some doubts that I cannot find answers on Core JavaServer Faces v3

Like this one...

How can the tag `h:commandButton` know which bean I am talking about ? I can only have one Bean per JSF page, is that it ? I am only giving it a msg.next which is a text from a i18n file.(quizbean is my bean)

```
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h3>#{msgs.heading}</h3>
        <p>
            <h:outputFormat value="#{msgs.currentScore}">
                <f:param value="#{quizBean.score}"/>
            </h:outputFormat>
        </p>
        <p>#{msgs.guessNext}</p>
        <p>#{quizBean.current.sequence}</p>
        <p>
            #{msgs.answer}
            <h:inputText value="#{quizBean.answer}"/>
        </p>
        <p><h:commandButton value="#{msgs.next}"/></p>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command button does not need to know this. All it generates is a HTML `<input type="submit">` element. This is embedded in a HTML `<form>` with an action URL pointing to the same URL as the page. There's further also the `<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState">`. Thanks to this field, JSF knows exactly what view you're submitting to. This view holds information about all inputs. This view knows that there's an `<h:inputText value="#{quizBean.answer}" />`. The view knows the field `name` of the generated HTML `<input type="text">` element. JSF will get the submitted request parameter value by `request.getParameter()` using this name and then update the `answer` property of the current instance of `quizBean` with this value.

Rightclick the page in your browser and choose *View Source* to see the JSF-generated HTML output. Put a breakpoint on `ApplyRequestValuesPhase#execute()` and `HtmlBasicRenderer#decode()` methods (assuming that you're using Mojarra not MyFaces) to track the gathering of submitted values for every `UIComponent` in the view.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. So it's just a plain submit button and JSF handles the finding and binding of the values by itself.

Answer (score 2):

The bean has to be managed by JSF, then it will know which bean you are talking about.

e.g.

```
<f:param value="#{quizBean.score}"/>
```

Here, the bean `quizBean` is a `Managed-Bean`, managed by JSF.

And to make it a managed bean you to tell JSF about it by either using annotations as follows -

```
@ManagedBean(name="quizBean") //name is optional or you give your own name to the bean
@SessionScoped //tell JSF in which scope you want to keep your managedbean
public class QuizBean {
    //....
```

Or by mentioning it as follows in the JSF configuration file (`faces-config.xml`) -

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>quizBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.pkg.QuizBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
//Older versions of JSF requires this where annotations do not work
//But if you are using JSF 2.0 then it's a lot better to use annotations
```

You can use more than one beans in a view (page).

Comment: So if I have 2 beans in the same page, it will updated both ? So the command button just pass the new states to the beans that are in that page?

Comment: @cfontes: In your case when the `commandButton` is clicked it's going update both `score` and `answer` properties of the `quizBean`.

Comment: @BheshGurung btw, your example might fail to deploy, since SessionScoped beans should implement Serializable.

Comment: @jFrenetic: I have got that warning a lot of times. But as far as failing to deploy, I have never had that. Have you? And also, it's not just the `session-scoped` ones, it's good make all managed-beans `Serializable`.

Comment: @BheshGurung It would surely fail, if you use CDI beans, because Weld-Deployer is much more intelligent. But I doubt about JSF-managed beans. However, it's still good practise to implement Serializable, for passivating scopes.

Comment: @cfontes: Sorry, it's not going to update `quizBean.score` because you are using it with `f:param`. Just know that if bind a managedbean-property is bound to a input-component then that property will be update with the value in the input-component when the form, in which the input-component is, is submitted.

Comment: @jFrenetic: You are right. I had never used CDI. Just tried it without Serializable and it failed to deploy.

Comment: Yeah correct it's a param... thanks for the points. about this serializable, someone should send it to Prentice because it's exatcly what's on the book.

Comment: @cfontes `about this serializable, someone should send it to Prentice because it's exatcly what's on the book` Are you kidding? Of course, there is not such code in the book. Moreover, it explicitly states on page 40, that `session-scoped` CDI beans **must** implement the Serializable interface`

Answer (score 1):

If this is an example from `Core Java Server Faces`, then read more carefully, it explains everything.

`msgs` as far as I remember, refers to **message bundle**, declared in **faces-config.xml**.

As for your question `how commandButton knows which bean to call`. In your example, the class name *QuizBean*, most likely correspond to the bean with the same name. That's enough for **JSF 2.0**. However, you could change that name by 2 methods:

1) If you use JSF managed beans, you should go like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="quiz")
@ViewScoped
public class QuizBean { }
```

2) If you use **CDI**-beans you would do this:

```
@Named("quiz")
@RequestScoped
public class QuizBean {}
```

**Remember** that CDI-beans scope annotations come from package *javax.enterprise.context*. And JSF scopes are in the *javax.faces.bean* package. ***Do not mix them!***

**Update:**
Please refer to **page 35** of the book [Core Java Server Faces 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012896) for more details about your question and do not hurry to ask questions if you don't understand something right away.

Comment: Ok, thanks I am using Named and CDI... And the book just hit the ground running in chapter 1 about this type of calls, I think it assumes you have used JSF 1.

Comment: Well, not really... You can start reading this book, without prior knowledge of JSF. Your question was about #{msgs.next}. And I remember it covers a lot of ground about message bundles.